# Как отследить нажатие клавиши в Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Мне нужно выполнять определённый код при зажатой клавише **1** и клике на клавишу **q**. Как и через какую библиотеку можно это реализовать? Приложение консольное.

Answer (score 5):

Как вариант использовать библиотеку keyboard
Но вообще-то это странная комбинация 1q 
Обычно используется <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>shift</kbd> а потом клавиша.
не знаю как q1. Но человеческие комбинации работают в keyboard

```
import keyboard
...

keyboard.add_hotkey('Ctrl + right', MoveRight)
```

Дополнено:
Проверил.. q+1 работает

```
import keyboard
import time

def fclick():
    print('click')


keyboard.add_hotkey('q + 1', fclick)
while True:
      time.sleep(1)
      print('while')
```